# C# Strange Index Out Of Bounds exception

Tags: c#, outlook, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a strange problem with an Index Out of Bounds exception when debugging an addin I am developing for MS Outlook 2010. I have a class to make message processing and in the constructor for that class, I pass a MailItem. I then intend to run through the Recipients list of the MailItem, and find all recipients registered in the To, CC, and BCC fields. For this I have the following code:

```
public MessageProcessor(Outlook.MailItem theMail)
{
  _activeMailItem = theMail;
  _activeMailDetails.Sender = theMail.SenderEmailAddress;
  if (_activeMailItem.Recipients.Count > 0)
  {
    List<string> recipients = new List<string>();
    List<string> cc = new List<string>();
    List<string> bcc = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _activeMailItem.Recipients.Count; i++)
    {
      switch (_activeMailItem.Recipients[i].Type)    <----- HERE
      {
        case (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo:
           recipients.Add(_activeMailItem.Recipients[i].Address);
           break;
        case (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC:
           cc.Add(_activeMailItem.Recipients[i].Address);
           break;
        case (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC:
           bcc.Add(_activeMailItem.Recipients[i].Address);
           break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get the exception at the point marked "HERE". When I debug and look at the value of the Recipients.Count property, it shows 1. However, the problem occurs when the "i" index is 0 (which should be a valid index - and, in this case, the only valid index). When I try to look at the _activeMailItem.Recipients collection, I see the Count of 1; however, when I try to track further down in the structure, I see some red crosses, and I can't inspect the values below that.

Does anyone have a clue about what can be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `i = 1`, if it works you know the collection is 1 based as some office com stuff is.

Comment: From the docs it looks like `Recipients` should allow you to index as usual, but just in case it works more like a dictionary, try foreach:ing over the collection instead.

Comment: Just a note for completeness: Foreach on COM proxies works in most cases at first glance, but is very leaky and can make outlook crash with unmanaged exceptions seemlingly unrelated to your code. So avoid and go with the answer to this question.

Answer (score 10):

All collections in Outlook (including Recipients) are 1 based, not 0:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= _activeMailItem.Recipients.Count; i++)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that; I didn't think about that it was different with the index. But now it works when using 1-based index. Thanks again.